# How to create user for the current session only in Linux?

Tags: linux, users

Is it possible to create a user without writing to the `/etc/passwd` file, so that the user only exists in the memory? `adduser` doesn't have an option for doing this. I don't think this is possible from the command line, so a solution in C code would be fine.

I should probably say that I want to make an app that lets users sign in to an administration like a school or company. I thought I'd tackle it by having the app start up before the display manager and add the users that the administration has set up

Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I wanted to make an app that lets users sign in to an administration like a school or company. I thought I'd tackle it by having the app start up before the display manager and add the users that the administration has set up.

Comment: Samuel, if the app would "_add the users that the administration has set up_" then why can't they be in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: @roaima I was thinking of how chromebooks did it, but now that I think about it chromebooks do store the users on the machine. I was just confused for a bit, but I'll set it up to use ```/etc/passwd/```. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do. It is possible to have system users (not people users that can not login), and groups. It is possible for a process to be owned by a user/group that is not registered in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`. But without knowing what you are trying to do, it is hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a user without writing to the `/etc/passwd` file…

Yes. It's quite possible to include user accounts that are managed from a remote database such as Microsoft's Active Directory (or the Samba equivalent), or LDAP, or even NIS. Some of the machines I manage where I work have exactly this configuration, which is managed through a combination of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and PAM (files in `/etc/pam.d` - [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pam), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module), [3](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pluggable-authentication-modules-pam))

> …so that the user only exists in the memory

Since it's quite possible to add additional authentication/authorisation services such as LDAP it should be possible to create a database of ephemeral accounts. However, I don't believe there is anything available "out of the box" that would achieve this.

I still think there's a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/286107) here - it's unclear to me why you would want user accounts that would disappear when a machine was restarted. For example, what should happen to files owned by such users?